# drivers for Samsung MBG4C eMmc harddrive

Tags: drivers, windows, windows-7, hard-drive, ubuntu-drivers

Where can I find drivers for Samsung MBG4C eMmc harddrive? Windows 7 compatible drivers would also be nice

Answer (score 1):

The drivers should be included with the standard linux kernel and there should be nothing to install.

Unlike windows, most drivers are included in the mainline kernel. You will notice you don't have to wait for "installing device drivers" every time you plug something into the USB port.

That is not to say that you will never need to install any firmware but that is usually only the case for a few very specific and sometimes unsupported wifi cards and or graphics cards etc.